# Showing the $n$-th derivative of $\cos x$ by induction

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, induction

I was asked to show that the $n$-th derivative of $\cos x$ is $\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2} + x)$.

My progress :

By induction, I proved it was true for $n=1$. Then I assumed it was true for $n = k$ so now I had to prove it was true for $n=k+1$.
$$ \cos\left(\frac{\pi(k+1)}{2} + x \right)$$
$$ = \cos\left(\frac{k\pi+\pi}{2} + x \right)$$
$$ = \cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2} + x \right).$$

Can somebody please assist me into proving my answer? Thanks.

Comment: Can a moderator please delete the question? I have understood the answer.

Comment: No; someone may want to view the question for help with similar issues. The site isn't just for answering questions then removing them.

Comment: No, the question stays. Moderators have been notified of the defacing you are attempting.

Comment: @user108104 That's got to be the third time you've defaced it, right? The site isn't just about you. Thanks for getting a mod, Andres.

Comment: @user108104 why are you so determined to have your question removed from the site, even after other users have nicely explained why your question should stay up?

Comment: Because I would like to ask a question similar to this one so it will be a duplicate.

Comment: @user108104 when a moderator arrives he will restore the question and lock it so you cannot vandalize it. You should accept this with grace, or you may end up getting formally reprimanded or worse.

Comment: @user108104 if the question is dissimilar enough to warrant a separate post, then there will be no problem with that. Just be sure to emphasize how your second question differs from this one in your question, and perhaps link this one. Your current behavior is likely to lead to a situation where you can no longer ask *any* questions.

Comment: @user108104 If you have another question, ask it. If it's the same question, don't. Seems simple, no? Don't remove information because it's not useful to you (the site is for archiving answers, not just writing them).

Answer (score 6):

Next use the identity for $\cos(a+b)$, where here $a = \frac{k \pi}{2} + x$ and $b = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Well I then went off to say that it follows by $$cos(\frac{k\pi+\pi}{2}).cosx -sin(\frac{k\pi+\pi}{2}).sinx$$ . I don't know what to do next

Comment: You need to read what I said again. Group the terms differently before applying the identity.

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant to say that I got $$ -sin(\frac{k\pi}{2}+x) $$ and I do not know the value of $k$, so I wouldn't know how to reduce it.

Comment: OK, so what are you trying to show? What is the $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ derivative of $\cos x$ according to the inductive hypothesis? You want to show that the expression you just got is equal to the first derivative of that, right?

Comment: I am trying to prove that it is true for $n = k+1 $

Comment: Right. So saying that it is true for $n=k+1$ means that the expression you got is equal to the $(k+1)^{\mathrm{st}}$ derivative of $\cos x$. You can compute that derivative by taking the derivative of the $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ derivative --- and you know what the $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ derivative is by the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: I don't know what the kth derivative is. I assumed it was true to work out what $ (k+1)st $ derivative of cos$x$ which is what I have shown above.

Comment: Exactly. You are using induction, and that is your inductive hypothesis (assumption). You are assuming that the $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ derivative is $\cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{2} + x\right)$.

Comment: So I have basically finished the proof?

Comment: Why don't you post your entire proof as an edit to your question, and then we can continue if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Let the result be true for $n=k$

Therefore, the $k$-th derivative of $\cos x$ is $\cos (\frac{k\pi}{2}+x)$

So, the $(k+1)$-th derivative is 
\begin{align}
-\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2}+x\right)\cdot 1
&=-\sin \left(\frac{(k+1)\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}+x\right)\\
&=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{(k+1)\pi}{2}-x\right) && \text{(Since $\sin(-x)=-\sin x$)}\\
&=\cos \left(\frac{(k+1)\pi}{2}+x\right)
\end{align}

Hence the proof, by induction.

Answer (score 3):

If you are familiar with complex numbers, here is another point of view : for $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $\Re(z)$ denotes the real part of $z$.

Note that, for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $\cos(x) = \Re \big( e^{ix} \big)$.

If $f$ denotes the function $x \, \mapsto \, e^{ix}$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\displaystyle f^{(n)}(x) = i^{n} e^{ix} $ ($f^{(n)}$ is the $n$-th derivative of $f$). Since $i = e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}}$, you get :

$$ f^{(n)}(x) = e^{ix + in\frac{\pi}{2}} $$

Taking the real part gives :

$$ \Re \big( f^{(n)} \big)(x) = \cos \big( x + n\frac{\pi}{2} \big) $$

As a consequence,

$$ \cos^{(n)}(x) = \Re \big( f^{(n)} \big)(x) = \cos \big( x + n\frac{\pi}{2} \big). $$

Comment: .... the best answer!  +1

Answer (score 0):

You should also be careful about what you are actually trying to prove. The inductive hypothesis should be

$$\textrm{Assume that } \frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left(\cos x\right) = \cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2} + x\right).$$

Differentiate both sides, then try to rewrite the resulting right-hand side as you mention in your question to get it into the desired form.

Answer (score 0):

You could set $y=x+\frac {n\pi}2$ and use the chain rule to prove the inductive step.